# Java, Exceptions in thread main LWJGL

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

For some reason eclipse just does stuff on its own..
I have the lwjgl.jar & -util.jar & slick.util Jars inside the java build path
aswell..

Code:

```
package Com.Window;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

public class Window {

    public void start() {

        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // init OpenGL here

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

            // render OpenGL here

            Display.update();
        }
        Display.destroy();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window window = new Window();
        window.start();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at Com.Window.Window.start(Window.java:12)
    at Com.Window.Window.main(Window.java:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

1:
Create a .bat file and put -Djava.library.path="lib/"

2.
Do it programmatically (first line of code)

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/lib/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [JClassics answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28161268/3636680):

If you kept the file structure from the LWJGL package you can use something like this:

```
switch(LWJGLUtil.getPlatform())
{
    case LWJGLUtil.PLATFORM_WINDOWS:
    {
        JGLLib = new File("./native/windows/");
    }
    break;

    case LWJGLUtil.PLATFORM_LINUX:
    {
        JGLLib = new File("./native/linux/");
    }
    break;

    case LWJGLUtil.PLATFORM_MACOSX:
    {
        JGLLib = new File("./native/macosx/");
    }
    break;
}

System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", JGLLib.getAbsolutePath());
```